# Issue with Easy Booking plugin and Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We are using the Easy Booking plugin for a client’s project and they want the ability to make the dates recurring. I.E they use the calendar to book Mon, Tues and Wed and want to have it recurring for the next 3 weeks.

We added some JS functionality, with a few form fields, that modifys the data-booking_price so that it is the price * recurring modifier.  The order flow works fine while the quantity is one, but if we increase the quantity, the whole thing breaks apart. After we add the item to the cart and then go to View Cart, the price is set to the original booking price, sans the modifier.

You can view it in action here: http://bethpark.dev.ksand.com/product/meter-bags

My question is how does how does the plugin pass the total of the product along to the cart? From what I can see, it’s not updating Woo Sessions with the total that is getting generated. Is that not accurate? I realize we are modifying how the plugin inherenly works, but any sort of pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated!

-Anthony

I've updated WC()->cart->total on both the cart page and the checkout page, but it keeps getting overwritten. I've also manually set the total in WC()->sessions but that also get's overwritten (I've since commented these out since this felt extremely hacky.)

```
//function to detect if PHP session is started
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' , 'bpa_custom_add_checkout_fields', 50, 0 );

function save_recursion(){
//if the user is getting the bags with recursive dates set, we will attempt to save them so that they can be used at a later time.

    if( isset($_POST['recursive_weeks']) ){
        $id = 0;

        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            $id = get_current_user_id();
        }
        // if user is not logged in or if WP couldn't get user ID
        if($id > 0){
            update_user_meta($id, 'bpa_meter_bag_recursion', $_POST['recursive_weeks']);
        } else {
            if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
            $_SESSION['bpa_meter_bag_recursion'] = $_POST['recursive_weeks'];
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'save_recursion');


function custom_add_to_cart( $item_data, $cart_item) {

    //this adds the custom recursion dates to the items data

    //if this is the meter bag product
    if($cart_item['product_id'] == '2476'){ 

        //check if user is logged in, get recursion from user meta. if not try to get sessions
        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            $id = get_current_user_id();
            $recursion = get_user_meta($id, 'bpa_meter_bag_recursion');
             $_POST['recursive_weeks'];
        } else {
            session_start();
            $recursion = $_SESSION['bpa_meter_bag_recursion'] ;
        }

        // change the message to reflect that this is going to be multiple dates
        $item_data[0]['name'] = "First Day of First Week";
        $item_data[1]['name'] = "Last Day of First Week";

        //get that first week dates in the correct format
        $start_date = new DateTime($item_data[0]['value']);
        $end_date = new DateTime($item_data[1]['value']);
        $first_start_date = $start_date->format('Y-m-d'); 
        $first_end_date =$end_date->format('Y-m-d');


        //iterate over the recursive weeks and add these as products to the cart
        $week = 1;
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; 
        for($i = 1; $i <= ($recursion[0] * 2) - 2; $i++ ){

            if( ($i % 2) != 0){
                $item_data[$i + 1]['name'] = "First Day of the Next Week ";
                $startDate = strtotime( $first_start_date . " +" . $week ." week"  );
    $item_data[$i + 1]['value'] = date('F jS Y', $startDate);
            } else {
                $item_data[$i + 1]['name'] = "Last Day of the Next Week ";
                $endDate = strtotime( $first_end_date . " +" . $week ." week");
                $item_data[$i + 1]['value'] = date('F jS Y',  $endDate);
                $week++;
            }

        }

        if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
        $_SESSION['recursive_dates'] = serialize($item_data);

        if( isset($_SESSION['recursive_dates']) ){
            //var_dump($_SESSION['recursive_dates']);
        }


        return $item_data;

        }

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 2);
```

What I am expecting to have happen is that on the product screen, the updated product total would get added to the cart total, and viewable from the cart and checkout. This works until the quantity is increased. Not sure why this is an issue since I would presume that the total would be prod_total * quantity, but that doesn't appear to be how this works. I'm not sure if this is a woo thing or an Easy Bookings thing (I'm tending to lean towards a woo thing, but my hours of research hasn't found anything, or I'm googling the wrong stuff. )

Any help in pointing me in the right direction is mucho appreciated.